# reactjs redux, is it possible to have a state use by 2 components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am having this error:

> bundle.js:2586 Warning: Failed propType: Invalid prop `posts` of type `array` supplied to `DisplayTrendings`, expected `object`. Check the render method of `Connect(DisplayTrendings)`.

And I have 2 lists that display items from an ajax call.

Here is my container:

```
export default class DisplayTrendings extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { dispatch } = this.props;
    dispatch(fetchPosts('trendings'));
  }

  render() {
    const { posts, isFetching } = this.props;
    console.log("posts in container :", posts['wikipedia']);
    const isEmpty = posts.length === 0;
    return (
      <Card className="card-main">
          <h2 className="trending-title">Trendings</h2>
          <ColumnName />

          {isEmpty
            ? (isFetching ? <h2>Loading...</h2> : <h2>Empty request.</h2>)
            : <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-6">
                  <DisplayWikiList style={{ opacity: isFetching ? 0.5 : 1 }} postsWiki={posts['wikipedia']} />
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-6">
                  <DisplayBroadmatchList style={{ opacity: isFetching ? 0.5 : 1 }} postsBroad={posts['broadmatch']} />
                </div>
              </div>
          }

          <div className="col-md-6">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-xs-6">
                <input type="text" className="bespoke-label" />
              </div>
              <DisplayOutPut />
            </div>
          </div>
      </Card>
    );
  }
};

DisplayTrendings.propTypes = {
  posts: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  isFetching: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  dispatch: PropTypes.func
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  console.log("state: ", state);
  const {
    isFetching,
    items: posts
  } = {
    isFetching: state.posts.isFetching,
    items: state.posts.items
  }
  return {
    posts,
    isFetching
  };
};
```

And here are my 2 components:

```
export default class DisplayBroadmatchList extends Component {
  render() {
    if (this.props.postsBroad) {
    return (
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-6">
          <ul>
            {this.props.postsBroad.map((post, i) =>
              <li key={i}>{ post.MarkerName }</li>
            )}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
    } else {
      return (
        <div></div>
      );
    }
  }
};
DisplayBroadmatchList.propTypes = {
  postsBroad: PropTypes.object
};

export default class DisplayWikiList extends Component {
  render() {
    if (this.props.postsWiki) {
    return (
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-6">
          <ul>
            <li key="bui">yolo</li>
            {this.props.postsWiki.map((post, i) =>
              <li key={i}>{ post.Entity }</li>
            )}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    );      
    } else {
      return (
        <div></div>
      );
    }
  }
};
DisplayWikiList.propTypes = {
  postsWiki: PropTypes.object
};
```

**Only the second list, DisplayWikiList is displaying a list.
The other one is blank and it doesn't go through it!**

So I am wondering, **is it because I am using the same props into the 2 components**?

When I check the returns posts,
to my container it's :

`posts[
    ->broadmatch {object1{name, id}, object2{name, id}...}
    ->wikipedia [object1{name, id}, object2{name, id}...]
   ]`

and if I display what I send to my component:

posts['broadmatch'] = {object1{name, id}, object2{name, id}...}

**What am I really doing wrong here?**

Comment: It's because your `.propTypes` is wrong. You have a `.object` an you need a `.array`.

Comment: Well if I change object to array, I got the same error but it's opposite:
```Invalid prop `posts` of type `object` supplied to `DisplayTrendings`, expected `array`. ```

Comment: That would imply you're not changing all of them correctly.

Comment: Well there is only 3 propTypes requiring an object or array (both incorrect apparently), so it's hard to miss one.
But the problem is, why only one list is displaying and why the container (parent) has this error. Specially when the console show me that I am receiving objects from my json. (it's even write "object", hard to miss it)

Comment: You need to set the prop type to array when you expect the component to receive an array, and the prop type to object when you expect the component to receive an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React supports multiple data types given the same prop; so you don't have to limit yourself to one or the other:

```
DisplayWikiList.propTypes = {
    postsWiki: React.PropTypes.oneOfType([
         React.PropTypes.object,
         React.PropTypes.array
    ]),
};
```

Via https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html

**EDIT**
What you're doing is viable, meaning you are absolutely able to pass the same prop to multiple sub-components without issue. That said, it looks as though both your subcomponents are using the `.map()` function on the incoming prop data, but `.map()` can only be used by arrays, not objects. And it looks like `broadmatch` is an object, meaning the `map()` iterator will not work. Try using `_.map()` from [lodash](https://lodash.com/) or [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/).

```
{  
    _.map(this.props.postsWiki, (post, key) =>
        <li key={key}>{ post.Entity }</li>
    )
}
```

Comment: Hey thank you very much for this smart tips :)
Thanks to you my warnings are off, but I still have only one list displaying - it doesn't even go through it - , that bring me back to "main" question, is it because I am using the same prop for DisplayWiki and DisplayBroadmatch?

Comment: @JayCee Just updated the answer. Most likely an issue with using `.map()` on an object, instead of an array. But yet, passing the same prop to multiple sub-components is okay to do, and a common pattern.